# APScheduler Lost connection to my datatbase during runtime (Hosted app and database on digital ocean)

Tags: python, django, database, digital-ocean, apscheduler

I have an app that uses APScheduler to execute jobs and the interval of a job being executed is 8 days.

It was working fine for the first 2 weeks, but on the next scheduled run time, all the jobs had the same error. From what I could tell, they seem to have lost connection to the database, although nothing has been changed. I get this error:

> Job "auto (trigger: interval[8 days, 0:00:00], next run at:
> 2023-08-22 23:29:16 UTC)" raised an exception  Traceback (most recent
> call last):    File
> "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py",
> line 308, in _cursor
> return self._prepare_cursor(self.create_cursor(name))
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py",
> line 26, in inner
> return func(*args, **kwargs)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py",
> line 330, in create_cursor
> cursor = self.connection.cursor()
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  psycopg2.InterfaceError: connection already closed

Because of the error above, the program then produces the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):    File
> "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apscheduler/executors/base.py",
> line 125, in run_job
> retval = job.func(*job.args, **job.kwargs)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    File "/workspace/main/automate.py", line 7, in auto
> client = Client.objects.get(CLIENT_ID = client_id)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py",
> line 87, in manager_method
> return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    File
> "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py",
> line 633, in get
> num = len(clone)
> ^^^^^^^^^^    File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py",
> line 380, in
> self._fetch_all()    File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py",
> line 1881, in _fetch_all
> self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py",
> line 91, in **iter**
> results = compiler.execute_sql(
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py",
> line 1560, in execute_sql
> cursor = self.connection.cursor()
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py",
> line 26, in inner
> return func(*args, **kwargs)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py",
> line 330, in cursor
> return self._cursor()
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py",
> line 307, in _cursor
> with self.wrap_database_errors:    File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/utils.py",
> line 91, in **exit**
> raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value    File
> "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py",
> line 308, in _cursor
> return self._prepare_cursor(self.create_cursor(name))
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py",
> line 26, in inner
> return func(*args, **kwargs)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py",
> line 330, in create_cursor
> cursor = self.connection.cursor()
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  django.db.utils.InterfaceError: connection already closed`

Any time a job is about to be run, this error appears. When I access the database on my machine and add a job, it executes normally, so I don't know why there is a change in behavior. How can I resolve the error?

Comment: Could you add the relevant code? We can't assist you if we don't know what we are working with.

Comment: in the current format, this makes no sense.  please edit to make it readable.